# Simulate Win+R in Windows

Tags: c#, windows

I have a [program](https://github.com/qianlifeng/WinAlfred) that need to execute some commands like `iisreset` or `iexplore` or any other commands that <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> supports. Is there any existed API that I can invoke? Currently, I use following c# code that can only simulate parts of the commands of <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal, 
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C " + cmd
};    
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: To format a code block indent it with 4 spaces (or select it and hit Ctrl+K). That way you don't need to leave every second line empty and you get syntax highlighting for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx) flag to get the same behavior as the *Run* dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You can send command using following code:

```
 Process.Start("iexplore");
```